# Округление числа с заданной точностью

Tags: c, c++

Добрый вечер!

Есть некий код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void Round(double a, short b)
{
    double round,razn,st;
    int k;
    st=pow(10.0,b); 
    round=a*st; 
    cout<<round<<endl;
    k=(int)round; 
    razn=round-k; 
    cout<<razn<<endl;
    if(razn>=0.5) k=k+1; 
    cout<<k<<endl;
    round=k/st; 
    cout<<round<<endl;
}
void main()
{
    double a;
    short zn;
    cout<<"Enter the number: "<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"Number of decimal places: "<<endl;
    cin>>zn;
    Round(a,zn);
}
```

Почему, если ввести число, например, 12.121416, и указать отображать 5 символов, то выведет 12.1214, в общем всегда будет выводить не более 4 знаков после точки. Хотя в режиме отладчика переменная round будет корректно отображать нужное мне число "12.12142".

И если возможно, то как это победить?

Comment: Поинтересуйтесь манипуляторами вывода.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/

Comment: Спасибо, почитаю ;)

Comment: int случаем не ограничивает??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать Сишный метод [printf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).
У меня им получалось увидеть даже мусор на последних символах типа double :)